# Why linear regression choose to minimize the residual on y-axis but not the absolute error between prediction and measurement?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Does anyone know why linear regression choose to minimize only $(y_{predict} - y_{measured})^2$, but not $(y_{predict} - y_{measured})^2 + (x_{predict} - x_{measured})^2 $?

Comment: Minimizing $2(y_{predict} - y_{measured})^2$ leads to the same estimated coefficients as minimizing $(y_{predict} - y_{measured})^2$, as it just adds a constant factor. Hence, linear regression minimizes both of these objectives.

Comment: You are addressing the problem of total least square https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares which is much more difficult. This is a very good question. (+1)

Comment: See what's the inventor himself said in those days: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645198/query-on-the-standard-deviation-formula/3645250#3645250

Comment: Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia) and related pages.

Answer (score 0):

The linear regression belongs to the supervised learning methods: the methods that try to generate predictions of a variable (Y) from values of one or more variables(the Xs). X is consequently not predicted, but only observed, as a regressor. Y is the only variable that will be predicted, so you have to minimize the RSS that you wrote.