# Why do we use variance, standard deviations and median absolute deviation?

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation, means, descriptive-statistics

What is the difference of variances, standard deviation and MAD?, I mean, where  do we use each one?. Usually teachers teach that variance is just a step for get SD, and never use MAD, so, why do we use it?

Comment: I have never used MAD.  Standard deviation and variance have different units (as one is squared), so of course they'll find different uses.  Standard deviation is the easiest to "see" on a graph, but variances add (under very general conditions), so we use the statistic appropriate for the application.

Comment: For normal data inference for variances (tests and confidence intervals), hence also for standard deviations, is straightforward, using sample variances with chi-squared and F distributions. MAD is mainly used for non-normal data, and specific inferences using MAD may require simulation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, so, SD is for graphs and variance is for what? like what examples? just, they seems like the same, like the variance is only a step por SD

Comment: If you have $X_1 \sim {\cal N}[\mu_1, \sigma_1^2]$ and $X_2 \sim {\cal N}[\mu_2, \sigma_2^2]$, then $(X_1 + X_2) \sim {\cal N}[(\mu_1 + \mu_2 )/2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2]$.  *Very* useful theorem exploiting variances.

Comment: @BruceET No-normal data is for "weird" data, like having two data very far away from de median?

Comment: See here, please: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645198/query-on-the-standard-deviation-formula/3645250#3645250