# What does the variance's value mean intuitively?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

I get that the variance basically indicates how much the possible outcomes for a random variable are spread or how much they may differ from the expected value. The higher the variance the more they may differ from the expected value. But what exactly is the meaning of a specific value for the variance? What does it mean if the variance is one?

Comment: You can get some insight by studying the normal distribution. For a normal distribution, if the variance is 1, and the mean is 7, for example, 68% of all values sampled would be between 6 and 8. 95% would be between 5 and 9. And 99 percent would be between 4 and 10.

Comment: $\textrm{Var}[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$

Comment: the variance in a sense is an aggregate measure so there are many (infinite) situations where the variance is $1$.

Comment: For intuition, the square root of the variance, also known as the standard deviation, might be better. Unlike variance, it scales proportionally with the data (for instance, if you have data measured in meters, and you just convert everything to centimeters, the data is all multiplied by 100, the standard deviation is multiplied by 100, but the variance is multiplied by 10 000).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645198/query-on-the-standard-deviation-formula/3645250#3645250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance by itself does not convey how much a variable is spread. Variance may also be roughly regarded as a measure of fluctuation, or (in)consistency

Imagine a runner   who is training for a month for olympics.
If over the month her variance for the time taken to finish the practice race is 5 seconds, while the second athlete has 20 seconds, it does not mean first one is more consistent.

If the first runner is training for 400 metre race with the average  around 45 seconds, and the second runner is practising for 5000 metres with the average closer to 15 minutes, second athlete has a better consistency.

Moral is, without knowing what the expectation is variance can not be a meaningful measure of fluctuation.

Of course two random variables with identical mean and variance can also be significantly different: the distribution function gives the full info on the nature of random variables.

Comment: If each run is measured in seconds then variance is measured in seconds$^2$.

Comment: (-1) "Moral is, without knowing what the expectation is variance can not be a meaningful measure of fluctuation." I disagree with that way of putting it, as variance is *by definition* the mean of the squared "fluctuations" or "deviations from the mean", and [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) can be useful precisely when the expectation is *not* known. (The *significance* of one distribution having smaller variance than another is a different matter, and may depend on the respective expectations.)

Comment: @r.e.s.: I meant ratio of variance to mean relativising it is  required.

Comment: @Arthur: You are right. I had standard deviation in mind. The way I stated units don't match, a cardinal sin for physicists.